# jQuery custom order for .each()

Tags: jquery, each

I am successfully using .each() to fade in some blocks one after the other.  As expected it starts at the first element and moves on to the next in order.

Is there any way to control the order of .each()?  Instead of 1,2,3,4 and so on I'd like, for example, 1,2,5,9,6,3,4,7,8.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".blocks").each(function(i) {
       $(this).delay((i + 1) * 500).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use the `.get()` function to return the elements matched by `.blocks` in a JavaScript array, sort them in whatever order you like, wrap them in another jQuery object, then iterate over them using `.each()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a direct answer to your question, `.each()` iterates the items of a jQuery object in the order the items are in the jQuery internal array.  There is no way to control the order that `.each()` uses other than changing the order in the array that it's iterating.

Since you don't disclose how the desired order would be determined algorithmically, your options are:

1. Sort the array before `.each()` is called
2. Manually create the desired order before the `.each()` call
3. Some other piece of code that orders the array appropriately before the `.each()` call

In the very specific instance of your code snippet, you could solve it differently without reordering `.each()` or reordering the array by creating a lookup table that would look up the desired delay value for a given array index.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var delayLookup = {1:1,2:2,5:3,9:4,6:5,3:6,4:7,7:8,8:9};
    $(".blocks").each(function(i) {
       var delayTime = delayLookup[i] || i;
       $(this).delay(delayTime * 500).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you put me on the right track - I decided to calculate the delayTime based on the index number (i).  Within .each() I have provided a value for delayTime so I can specify the order in which the blocks appear.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the logic of your order is. If you meant random, you can do this:

```
$('.blocks')
    .sort(function(item) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1; })
    .each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay((i + 1) * 500).fadeIn(500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to sort your array the way you want, here it seems to be quite a random sorting so you have to create an array and fill elements manually. Then you can call the each function.